# How can I combine two dictionaries with the same keys and values, ignoring string values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset as follows,

```py
[
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 4, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 2, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'},
  {'sets': 2, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'}
]
```

I want to merge two dictionaries if their value is less than or equal to 2. For instance, when we look at the data above, the output should be as follows,

```py
[
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 4, 'muscle': 'Chest', 'body_part': 'Upper'},
  {'sets': 4, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'},
  {'sets': 3, 'muscle': 'Abdominal', 'body_part': 'Abdominal'}
]
```

As you can see, there were two sets of "Abdominal" with 2 and these were combined to make 4 sets. Also, other string values (`muscle` and `body_part`) are still here.

I tried this and found the items to replace but I still need to remove the actual values from the data.

```py
replaces = {}

for part in data:
    if part['sets'] == 2:
        if part['muscle'] not in replaces:
            replaces[part['muscle']] = []
            
        replaces[part['muscle']].append({
            'sets': part['sets'],
            'muscle': part['muscle'],
            'body_part': part['body_part']
        })
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't change the list while iterating through it you would have to memorize all indices which you want to delete. I would probably do something like this:

```py
same_parts_le_2 = {}
deletion_list = []
for idx, part in enumerate(data):
    if part["sets"] <= 2:
        key = (part["muscle"], part["body_part"])
        if key not in same_parts_le_2:
            same_parts_le_2[key] = [part["sets"], idx]
        else:
            same_parts_le_2[key][0] += part["sets"]
            deletion_list.append(idx)

for value in same_parts_le_2.values():
    data[value[1]]["sets"] = value[0]

for idx in sorted(deletion_list, reverse=True):
    data.pop(idx)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to manipulating the data in dictionaries directly, I propose using `pandas` as it is really good with this type of structured data (as you can easily sort/aggregate your data too):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfnew = df[df.sets <=2].groupby([ 'muscle', 'body_part'], as_index=False).sum()
dfnew = pd.concat([df[df.sets >2], dfnew])
# dfnew.to_dict('records') # to convert to original format
print(dfnew)
```

Output:

```
   sets     muscle  body_part
0     3      Chest      Upper
1     3      Chest      Upper
2     4      Chest      Upper
4     3  Abdominal  Abdominal
6     3  Abdominal  Abdominal
0     4  Abdominal  Abdominal
```